# How can I do set operation checks in a MongoDB query (superset, subset, union)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have a collection of jobs:

```json
    {
       _id: ObjectId("1"),
       tags: []
    }
    {
       _id: ObjectId("2"),
       tags: ["A"]
    }
    {
       _id: ObjectId("3"),
       tags: ["A", "B"]
    }
    {
       _id: ObjectId("4"),
       tags: ["A", "B", "C" ]
    }
```

How can I query some jobs based on set operations between the job `tags` and some `query_tags`? Specifically:

1. Get all jobs where `tags` is a SUPERset of `query_tags`

   Example: `query_tags = ["A", "B" ]` -> Get jobs with ids 3 and 4
2. Get all jobs where `tags` is a SUBset of `query_tags`

   Example: `query_tags = ["A", "XXXX"]` -> Get jobs with ids 1 and 2
3. Get all jobs where the union of `tags` and `query_tags` is not empty

   Example: `query_tags = ["A", "XXXX"]` -> Get jobs with ids 2, 3 and 4

   Example 2: `query_tags = ["B", "XXXX"]` -> Get jobs with ids 3 and 4

Notes:
For case 1, I can probably use [$all](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/), but what about case 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1):

1. superset: use `$setIsSubset`

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    "$setIsSubset": [
      [
        "A",
        "B"
      ],
      "$tags"
    ]
  }
})
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U-JHw8n2e0h) for your reference.

---

2. subset: use `$setIsSubset`, but in reverse

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    "$setIsSubset": [
      "$tags",
      [
        "A",
        "XXXX"
      ]
    ]
  }
})
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T3zhG3u8CqJ) for your reference.

---

3. set union: This one is a bit confusing to me. As long as your `query_tags` is non-empty, the set union will always be non-empty so every documents should be returned. Nevertheless, you can use `$setUnion`.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $ne: [
      {
        "$setUnion": [
          "$tags",
          [
            "A",
            "XXXX"
          ]
        ]
      },
      []
    ]
  }
})
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UKjJTSh3HHD) for your reference.